# ¿Cómo subir un proyecto de Laravel a mi hosting correctamente?

Tags: laravel

Hice un proyecto en `laravel` ,use las plantillas de el login y register que viene por `default` en `laravel` y me funciono correctamente en mi `localhost` , luego lo subí a mi hosting y no me sale todo bien hasta el `welcome` de `Laravel` , pero no me sale ni el register ni el login me sale el siguiente error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien que haya tenido el mismo error es la primera vez que subo un proyecto en laravel a un hosting siempre lo hice desde la propia máquina

Comment: Ya cambiaste los datos de tu .env para configurar base de datos ?

Comment: si, ahora que vi en el network me sale register not found y cuando le doy click no aparece nada, a diferencia en el localhost si me carga el formulario de register entonces estaria mal lo de las rutas, pero donde tendria que configurar eso

Comment: Tienes que configurar en tu servidor que el directorio principal es la carpeta public

Comment: no creo que sea eso, en ese caso no me cargaria nada pero si me carga la parte principal, y los link de Login y Register

Comment: Mira esto https://laraveles.com/laravel-servidor-compartido/

Comment: Puedes subir la configuración de tu vhost?

Comment: Tu hosting que es ? Una máquina Linux con Lamp? Un cPanel ?

Answer (score 0):

probaste con verificar los datos del archivo .env? en caso de que no, generate un archivo .env en la raiz del proyecto.

Por otra parte, instalaste composer en este nuevo hosting? verifica eso e intenta hacer composer update para que instale todas las dependencias del proyecto.

Saludos